# which of the two is a better way of creating and destroying objects?

Tags: java

i have a question on lines 26 & 27:

```
String dumb = input.nextLine();
output.println(dumb.replaceAll(REMOVE, ADD));
```

i was hoping that i'd be able to shrink this down to a single line and be able to save space, so i did:

```
output.println(new String(input.nextLine()).replaceAll(REMOVE, ADD));
```

but now i'm wondering about performance.  i understand that this program is quiet basic and doesn't need optimization, but i'd like to learn this.
the way i look at it, in the first scenario i'm creating a string object dumb, but once i leave the loop the object is abandoned and the JVM should clean it up, right?  but does the JVM clean up the abandoned object faster than the program goes through the loop?  or will there be several string objects waiting for garbage collection once the program is done?

and is my logic correct that in the second scenario the String object is created on the fly and destroyed once the program has passed through that line?  and is this in fact a performance gain?

i'd appreciate it if you could clear this up for me.

thank you,

p.s. in case you are wondering about the program (i assumed it was straight forward) it takes in an input file, and output file, and two words, the program takes the input file, replaces the first word with the second and writes it into the second file.  if you've actually read this far and would like to suggest ways i could make my code better, PLEASE DO SO.  i'd be very grateful.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class RW {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String INPUT_FILE = args[0];
        String OUTPUT_FILE = args[1];
        String REMOVE = args[2];
        String ADD = args[3];

        File ifile = new File(INPUT_FILE);
        File ofile = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);

        if (ifile.exists() == false) {
            System.out.println("the input file does not exists in the current folder");
            System.out.println("please provide the input file");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Scanner input = new Scanner(ifile);
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(ofile);

        while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            String dumb = input.nextLine();
            output.println(dumb.replaceAll(REMOVE, ADD));
        }
        input.close();
        output.close();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very, very first thing I'm going to say is this:

Don't worry about optimizing performance prematurely. The Java compiler is smart, it'll optimize a lot of this stuff for you, and even if it didn't you're optimizing out *incredibly tiny* amounts of time. The stream IO you've got going there is already running for orders of magnitude longer than the amount of time you're talking about.

What is *most* important is how easy the code is to understand. You've got a nice code style, going from your example, so keep that up. Which of the two code snippets is easier for someone *other than you* to read? *That* is the best option. :)

That said, here are some more specific answers to your questions:

1. Garbage collection will absolutely pick up objects which are instantiated inside the scope of a loop. The fact that it's instantiated inside the loop means that Java will already have marked it for clean up as soon as it fell out of scope. The next time GC runs, it will clean up all of those things which have been marked for clean up.
2. Creating an object inline will still create an object. The constructor is still called, memory is still allocated... Under the hood, they are really, really similar. It's just that in one case that object has a name, and in the other it doesn't. You're not going to save any real resources by combining two lines of code into one.
3. "input.nextLine()" already returns a String, so you don't need to wrap it in a new String(). (So yes, removing that actually *will* result in one less object being instantiated!)

Answer (score 1):

Local Objects are eligible for GC once they go out of scope. That does not mean that GC cleans them that very moment. The eligible objects undergone a lifecycle. GC may or may not collect them immediately.

As far your program is concerned, there is nothing much to optimize except a line or two. Below is a restructured program.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String INPUT_FILE = args[0];
        String OUTPUT_FILE = args[1];
        String REMOVE = args[2];
        String ADD = args[3];

        File ifile = new File(INPUT_FILE);
        File ofile = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);
        if (ifile.exists() == false) {
            System.out.println("the input file does not exists in the current folder\nplease provide the input file"); 
            System.exit(0);
        }
        Scanner input = null;
        PrintWriter output = null;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(ifile);
            output = new PrintWriter(ofile);
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                output.println(input.nextLine().replaceAll(REMOVE, ADD));
            }
        } finally {
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
            if(output != null)
                output.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you arew concerned about obejct creation and performance, use a profiler to mesure your code. And keep in mind that doing `new String(input.nextLine())` is totally pointless since `input.nextLine()` returns an immutable instance of String. So just do `output.println(input.nextLine().replaceAll(REMOVE, ADD));`.

Comment: i actually tried doing that so that i wouldn't call the string object, my mistake was in not typing it like this:

    output.println(input.nextLine.replaceAll(REMOVE, ADD));

 i was missing the parenthesis for the nextLine() method..